# Unable to use HashMap when compiling apache james server 2.3.1

Tags: java, sql, james

I am unable to use a synchronized HashMap because it seems like james apache server 2.3.1 doesn't allow so.

This is the error message I am getting:

```
error: generics are not supported in -source 1.4
Map<String, String> list = new HashMap<String, String>();
       ^
(use -source 5 or higher to enable generics)
1 error
1 warning
```

This is a shorter version of where I am using it in my code. I am basically just storing some SQL results into this list.

```
try {
    conn = ......);
    String SQL = "SELECT * FROM list";

    getListRS = conn.prepareStatement(SQL);

    ResultSet rsListResult = getListRS.executeQuery();

    Map<String, String> list = new HashMap<String, String>();

    while (rsListResult.next()) {
        list.put(rsListResult.getString(0), rsListResult.getString(1));
    }

    rsListResult.close();
    conn.close();
} 
catch (SQLException se) {
    se.printStackTrace();
}
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
finally {
    try {
        if (getListResult != null) {
            getListResult.close();
        }
    }
    catch (SQLException se2) {
        se2.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        if (conn != null) {
            conn.close();
        }
    }
    catch (SQLException se) {
        se.printStackTrace();
    }
}

if (this.list.containsKey(mail.getSender()+"="+mail.getRecipients())) {
    System.out.println(list);
    return mail.getRecipients();
} else {
    System.out.println(listlist);
    return null;
}
```

What other list can I use to achieve this since James is not letting me compile.

The error is at here:

```
      <javac destdir="${build.classes}" debug="${debug}" optimize="${optimize}" deprecation="${deprecation}" target="${jdk.target}" source="${jdk.source}">
```

Comment: is that the only error message you get?

Comment: This is an error from java compiler, what are you using to compile your classes? maven, ant?

Comment: Yeap, Thats the only error message. I couldn't compile. So Is there something similar to hashmap that I can use to compile with as I don't know how to change the source higher. As far as I know this server is very old and I don't think it supports further Java because I installed 1.4 jdk specially for it

Comment: @krzyk i am using ant or rather the program is using ant when building it

Comment: @Nicky Add build.xml to the question, the problem is probably there

Comment: then the version is the problem, because generics were introduced in java 1.5

Comment: @Nicky Where does the `jdk.source` and `jdk.target` come from?

Comment: @kryzyk i found it in a file called default.properties and jdk.source and target is pointing to 1.4, do i just change it to 1.5 to make it work or I do need jdk 1.5 in my system for it to work?

Comment: @Nicky Yes, you need java 1.5 on your system, but you already have it because you got that error, java 1.4 doesn't know anything about generics

Comment: @krzyk now I have another question about hashmap, do I start a new question or I can ask here?

Comment: @Nicky It is better to ask a new one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an error from java compiler.
In ant you define source level in javac tag, e.g.:

```
<javac target="1.5" source="1.5" .....>
```

(alternatively check default.properties file for `jdk.target` and `jdk.source` and change those to 1.5).

Use at least 1.5 level to allow generics.

BTW. To check what java version you have you can call `java -version` when you go to the jdk bin folder.

Answer (score 2):

since generics were introduced in java 1.5, all you can do now is to use raw HashMaps and use a lot of checks and casts

but the best thing would be to upgrade your java version